# Multiple websites sharing content from one central location?

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

At the moment I have three umbraco websites that each have their own content trees, but all have one page in common. At the moment, since all three sites are independent, the data is just copied into each site.

However our client is now asking that all the pages can be managed from **one** site. Ie. the data is updated in one umbraco installation and somehow mirrored across the other sites. Bear in mind this page is password protected and contains sensitive data.

How can I achieve this?

My first thought was maybe to expose an xml feed that contained all of the relevant data however I have no idea how I'd keep all the data secure. Would it be a case of encrypting and setting over https? I literally have no idea where to begin here.. can anyone point me in the correct direction?

I'm really looking for the simplest solution here.

Thanks

Comment: I have done a similiar thing before, I kept all page content in one table in database and created another table to match which content belongs to which website. It works for a year now without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have three separate web sites as implied by you saying coping data from one site to another, I would set up a web service on the main site where the data is edited. Then just put  macros on the other sites to display the data.

If it is sensitive data add a login and password to the web service and it would all have to be https.